# Scala class initialization

Tags: scala

I see this syntax in scala. `val variable = new SomeClass("arguments") {...}`. Why is there a body after `new` and how's it different from the java way of creating an object

Comment: Normally it is used to instantiate a trait, content in `{...}` will implement or override methods or val of that trait, same if SomeClass is a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's no just a instance of `SomeClass`, it's also an extension of that class. This syntax creates a *anonymous subclass* of `SomeClass` and instantiate the new subclass.

I don't think your question, as is, has anything to do with class initialization.